# How to add specific no. of months to a date in UNIX Timestamp format?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I've a field in MySQL table named **last_date** which has a data-type **bigint(12)**. In this field I'm storing the equivalent UNIX Timestamp values of dates.

Now I want to insert UNIX Timestamp value equivalent to the **five(5) months** from today's date. That is if today's date is

> 13/02/2014(dd/mm/yyyy format, 13th February 2014)

I want to insert the UNIX Timestamp equivalent of the date

> 13/07/2014(dd/mm/yyyy format, 13th July 2014)

Also if the year change is required then also it should work. Means if today's date is

> 13/11/2014(dd/mm/yyyy format, 13th November 2014)

then the equivalent UNIX Timestamp to be inserted should be of date

> 13/04/2015(dd/mm/yyyy format, 13th April 2015)

Which means year change should also be considered. Do anyone have any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want that to happen on PHP side or through MySql query ?

Comment: @Rikesh:Through MySQL query only. No data from the form side or user side(i.e. PHP) is involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql supports the use of INTERVAL for this type of operation

```
INSERT INTO table SET newdate = unix_timestamp(now() + INTERVAL 5 month);
```

Here is an example of it in action

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp(),unix_timestamp(now() + interval 5 month);
+------------------+------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp() | unix_timestamp(now() + interval 5 month) |
+------------------+------------------------------------------+
|       1392274422 |                               1405230822 |
+------------------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```